# How to evaluate if an asset's return distribution can be modeled by a Gaussian distribution?

Tags: rate-of-return

How to analyze the distribution of the return? Are there procedures for a bunch of tests to see how well it fits different distributions? Or derivation of formula from the stochastic process?

Comment: For a specific asset? Get its history and run the math. Books have been written on this topic. But remember that past is no guarantee of future, and it having looked stochastic in the past does not mean it will continue to be

Comment: Given that the range of possible returns is not symmetric implies that the returns cannot be considered truly Gaussian.

Comment: Yes, of course there are procedures to analyze the behavior of a time series. Whether this is of any relevance to investing is quite another question.

Comment: Any references that I can check out? @Kevin Arlin

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series

Comment: Remember that the existence of data is no guarantee that it is useful, typical, still relevant, or anything else. If it was that easy to predict, pros would do a lot better in the market than they demonstrably do.